# What's the major importance of Abstraction?

Tags: java

As a newbie in Java i would like to undestand some basic concepts , I'm on the Abstraction .. So i created this program to understand it 
Here is my program :

**First class (Parent class)**

```
public abstract class Myclass {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    abstract  void printvar();
}
```

**Second class (child class)**

```
public class MySecondClass extends Myclass  {
    public void  printvar() {
        System.out.println("a = "+a +" b = "+b);
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        MySecondClass inst = new MySecondClass();
        inst.printvar();
    }
}
```

I created a class as  ***abstract*** (**Myclass**)  and  i declared my  **abstract**  function (to be defined in  the inherited class **MySecondClass**)
I read that "*To achieve security - hide certain details and only show the important details of an object.*" so i imagine that i couldn't access to the class **Myclass** ...  So i can edit the function in the inherited class as i want to access some data (I knew the *private* keyword but without that) ! So no security if i can display other information using my abstract function :/ I misunderstand something ? Please help if so ;-)  .

Comment: Where did you read that quote? That quote should have said "To achieve _safety_...". They are very different things, and neither of which is related to abstraction.

Comment: W3school :here ==>  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_abstract.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean goal of the abstraction is hiding details and highly recommended for security reasons . I use usually interfaces more than abstract classes to hide the details of implementation, besides the advantages of programming against interfaces rather concrete classes to generate lose coupling code..

Comment: Yeah i see that too ,especially for the multiple inheritance ... Thank you man !